# Is work done relative according to the theory of special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, work, inertial-frames

I performed a thought experiment.

Consider a body $A$ and another body $B$.

Body $B$ is moving at velocity $v$ in direction $x$ with respect to $A$. This implies that body $A$ is moving at velocity $v$ in direction $-x$ with respect to $B$.

If work is done on body $B$, its velocity increases to $(v+dv)$ with respect to $A$ but the direction does not change.

Now, $B$ is moving in direction $x$ with velocity $(v+dv)$ with respect to A and A is moving with velocity $(v+dv)$ in direction $-x$ with respect to $B$.

$B$ says that work is done on $A$ whereas $A$ says that work is done on $B$.

This means that even workdone is relative. Is my reasoning correct?

**Edit**:- I am making this question more general. Since velocity is relative, does this mean that quantities arising from it like force, kinetic energy/workdone, momentum, acceleration, magnetic effects due to the movement of charges etc. relative?

Comment: Yes, energy ("workdone") is relative, not only in special relativity but also in classical Newtonian mechanics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This means that even workdone is relative. Is my reasoning correct?

Yes, work is relative. That means that in order to correctly specify the work you must clearly identify the reference frame.

> does this mean that quantities arising from it like force, kinetic energy/workdone, momentum, acceleration, magnetic effects due to the movement of charges etc. relative?

Most quantities that depend on velocity are indeed relative for the same reason. This includes KE, momentum, speed, etc.

There are some quantities that are a little more difficult. For instance, force and acceleration are relative to the reference frame in relativistic physics. But in Newtonian physics they are the same in all inertial frame. So sometimes the answer depends on the physical theory you are using.

Other quantities, like action or proper time, depend on velocity, but in a specific combination with other quantities that makes them not relative

Comment: Isn't that what I was saying yesterday? Today you got it right. In the meantime I was thinking about how to do this right in terms of teaching. Maybe we should introduce the concept of the momentum vector and the energy-momentum vector sooner into the high school curriculum. I think this might illustrate the reference frame dependence of kinetic energy better than the usual way of keeping velocity and energy separate.

Comment: @FlatterMann no, yesterday you were incorrectly saying that work is absolute. If you want to have a conversation please post to physicsforums.com

Comment: Then you misunderstood. I was arguing that one had to pick the correct reference frame to get a useful answer out of the kinetic energy formula. Inserting an arbitrary velocity into it leads to an arbitrary and unphysical result.

Comment: @FlatterMann if you want to have a conversation then please post to physicsforums.com Your argument is incorrect today and yesterday

Comment: I don't want to have a discussion about it. I am simply pointing out that "a reference frame" is not an abstract. It's actually the physical system of interest. I understand where you are coming from. In theory. In an experiment, however, kinetic energy is a well defined and unique number. It's what gets converted into deformation and gets thermalized when stuff hits the wall. You would have to get a different wall to get a different result. That's all. Let's leave it at that.

Comment: @FlatterMann why did you bother to comment here then? Your comments are wrong both yesterday and today. It is a bit frustrating to me because most of your posts are reasonable, but not only are you clearly wrong on this I have provided the math showing it to you. I think you should pursue this, but you need a different venue than PSE comments

Comment: I gave you an upvote and made a suggestion on how we can improve the teaching of these concepts in high school. I am far more interested in that part of it. If we teach E_kin = p_vect^2/2m, would that make it easier on the student to get used to the Galilean relativity business?

Comment: @FlatterMann maybe. I think that one of the challenges with Galilean relativity is that we teach it with displacement and velocity vectors and not forces, momenta, work, energy, power, acceleration, etc. We just stop too early

Comment: I think we are in full agreement on that. I am glad I am not the only person who thinks that.

Comment: @Dale, since velocity is relative, does this mean that all quantities arising from it like kinetic energy, acceleration, force, momentum, magnetic effects due to moving charges etc. -all are relative?

Comment: @Dale, please add the answer to the question in your answer instead of comments.

Comment: @AgnibhoDutta I will do so, but be aware that it is against site policy to edit a question in a way that invalidates answers you have ever received.

Comment: @Dale, I have edited my question by adding the other questions that arose in my mind later. So, I suppose the act shall not violate the laws of site

Comment: @AgnibhoDutta it does specifically violate the policy. You should not edit a question in a way that invalidates answers that you have already received. The policy is deliberately intended to stop adding other questions that arise in your mind later

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: @Dale, Sorry! I am new to this site. I will take care from next time.

Answer (score 0):

Work done = force*distance. Force is not relative because it can be measured using a device such as spring balace. Whatever this device registers is agreed upon by all reference frames. You can always determine in which frame the force was applied by checking where spring balance registered a non-zero value. This way you can tell where the work was done.

However, you can't determine where the work was done just by looking at velocities because they're relative, so is kinetic energy.